# UPDATE column with join

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

```
SELECT lott.id as lottery_id,lott.abbr,lott.currency,payments.id as payment_id,
    payment_prizes.prize_id,prizes.name,prizes.currency as prizes_currency
    FROM lotteries lott 
    JOIN lottery_payments payments 
        ON
        payments.lottery_id =  lott.id
    JOIN lottery_payment_prizes payment_prizes
        ON
        payment_prizes.payment_id = payments.id
    JOIN lottery_prizes prizes
        ON
        prizes.id =  payment_prizes.prize_id
    WHERE lott.currency = "ID"
```

I need to UPDATE all currency from lottery_prizes table WHERE id's are from query above.
I did this

```
UPDATE lottery_prizes SET currnecy = 'ID'
 WHERE id IN(SELECT prizes.id
    FROM lotteries lott 
    JOIN lottery_payments payments 
        ON
        payments.lottery_id =  lott.id
    JOIN lottery_payment_prizes payment_prizes
        ON
        payment_prizes.payment_id = payments.id
    JOIN lottery_prizes prizes
        ON
        prizes.id =  payment_prizes.prize_id
    WHERE lott.currency = "ID")
```

I have this error: 
**/* SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'lottery_prizes' for update in FROM clause */**
Thanks all

Comment: One of the annoying mysql flaws...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  UPDATE lottery_prizes l 
   JOIN (SELECT prizes.id
      FROM lotteries lott 
      JOIN lottery_payments payments 
          ON
          payments.lottery_id =  lott.id
      JOIN lottery_payment_prizes payment_prizes
          ON
          payment_prizes.payment_id = payments.id
      JOIN lottery_prizes prizes
          ON
          prizes.id =  payment_prizes.prize_id
      WHERE lott.currency = "ID") t
      ON t.Id = l.Id
 SET currency = 'ID'
```